# Firebase realtime number Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I'm developing a chat with firebase. Actually I'm sending audios between devices, saving it on the Storage ("new_audio"+number+".mp3") and saving that number on the Realtime Database (To know what was the last audio sended)
With the following code I can get the last number, and after that (when is uploading an audio) give him 1 more (number++).
When I start the chat with an user, the number is retrieved with out problems, but when the chat is open and User1 send an audio (new_audio3.mp3) and User2 send another audio after this dont retrieve the Number(Use the same audio number! new_audio3.mp3). **In short, the updated number is not received at the same time by the other device**, it works just when the chat was recently opened.

```
String audiosURL = "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/audios/" + UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith +"/audiosEnviados.json";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, audiosURL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            try{
                int numero = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
                System.out.println("------NUMERO DESDE BD------ "+numero);
                if (numero > 0) {
                    numeroJson = numero;
                } else {
                    numeroJson = -1;
                    //numeroJson = 0;
                }
            }catch(Exception E){
                numeroJson = 0;
            }

            reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                    String message = map.get("message").toString();
                    String userName = map.get("users").toString();

                    final String url = "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/"+UserDetails.username+"/amigos.json";
                    //ASIGNA EL NOMBRE DE AMIGO EN LA BARRA HEADER CHAT SEGÚN SU ANDROID ID
                    StringRequest requestAmigo = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String s) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                                Iterator i = obj.keys();
                                String key = "";
                                String keyNick = "";

                                while(i.hasNext()) {
                                    key = i.next().toString();
                                    if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                                        try {
                                            keyNick = obj.get(key).toString();
                                            if(UserDetails.chatWith.equals(key)){
                                                //UserDetails.chatWith = keyNick;
                                                headerArea.setText(keyNick);
                                                Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/Minecrafter.Reg.ttf");
                                                headerArea.setTypeface(custom_font);
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // Something went wrong!
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
                            //OJO COMENTE DISMISSSS
                            //pd.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    RequestQueue rQueueAmigos = Volley.newRequestQueue(Chat.this);
                    rQueueAmigos.add(requestAmigo);

                    if(userName.equals(UserDetails.username)){
                        //addMessageBox("  Tú:\n" + "  "+message + " \n", 1); el correcto
                        //addMessageBox(" Tú:\n" + " "+message + " \n \n", 1);
                        addMessageBox("  "+message + " \n", 1);
                    }
                    else{
                        //addMessageBox("  "+UserDetails.chatWith + ":\n" + "  "+message + " \n", 2); EL CORRECTO
                        //addMessageBox(" "+UserDetails.chatWith + ":\n" +" "+ message + " \n \n", 2);
                        addMessageBox("  "+message + " \n", 2);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Chat.this);
    rQueue.add(request);
```

Upload audio and save number (realtime firebase):

```
private void uploadAudio(){

        mProgress.setMessage("Enviando grabación ...");
        mProgress.show();

        System.out.println("NUMERO Antes de SUBIR JSON "+numeroJson);
        numeroJson++;
        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Audio").child(UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith).child("new_audio"+numeroJson+".mp3");
        System.out.println("NUMERO AL SUBIR JSON "+numeroJson);
        //SUBE NUMERO DE AUDIOS A SU LISTA
        Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/audios/"+UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
        reference.child("audiosEnviados").setValue(numeroJson);
        //SUBE NUMERO DE AUDIOS A LA LISTA DEL AMIGO
        Firebase reference2 = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/audios/"+UserDetails.chatWith + "_" + UserDetails.username);
        reference2.child("audiosEnviados").setValue(numeroJson);

        System.out.println("fpath "+filepath);
        System.out.println("filename "+mFileName);

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(dirTest+"/recorded_audio.mp3"));

        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope someone knows how to receive the number each time an audio is received / sent in the chat, THANKS <3!

Comment: If you change the same value I think you should use `onChildChanged` to detect the changes.

Comment: @AndréKool I thought the same thing, but it doesn't work, the change event is from the messages not from the request to the number of the audios, do you think it could change it?